# Is there a Jenkins plugin for downloading source code?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Although *our own* sources are checked out from a revision-control systems, the third-party software we depend on needs to be downloaded from their respective sites.

The plugin I'm looking for would offer a "Source Management" (or "Pre-Build") step, where I could register one (or more) sources for the same file. For example:

- https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz
- http://www2.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz
- http://www3.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz

and its digest (such as SHA256).

At build- (or at a prebuild-) time, it would check its cache and, if the file is not present there, download and verify it, and make it available to the subsequent build-steps.

I'm sure something like this, or very similar, exists already, but I cannot find it. Sonatype's Nexus seems to offer this, but only for files already found in one's Nexus repository, not for arbitrary URL's.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Job Cacher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobcacher) plugin?

To quote the plugin page:

> **Summary**
>
> Enables caching of files on transient executors for use on subsequent builds to improve performance
>
> **Features**
>
> - Item storage extension point supporting on master storage and AWS S3
> - Cache Wrapper for free style jobs that manages the cache
>   Arbitrary File Cache where user specifies paths to be cached
> - UI on Job page to review the job's caches
> - Supports Pipeline jobs with a cache directive
> - Cache Extension Point for other plugins to provide opinionated caching capability such as Gradle caches
> - Incremental storing of cache into storage to minimize data movement

However, these are for files **created** by the jobs, not **needed** by them. In order to use it in your case, you might need a few dummy jobs specifically for downloading the content from the arbitrary URLs, and then caching them in your Jenkins cache. I guess you'd have to write the script for that.

To be frank, I've never used this plugin, and what I describe above doesn't seem to be an elegant solution. Your question specifically ask for a Jenkins plugin, however I believe the *general* problem is **how to cache job dependencies** in Jenkins. If you agree to this wider interpretation, there are some other options.

I have often solved the problem you mention using a combination of managed scripts and persistent storage which Jenkins and workers have access to, in Jenkins.  If you need really *arbitrary* dependency management, a tool like [Spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io) or [EasyBuild](https://easybuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may be useful. Although these have evolved in the HPC domain, they do quite well at caching dependencies for workloads.

However, since you mention just a few dependencies (specific sqlite versions *e.g.*), I think it may be worth your time to write a script which does the caching for you and, together with globally-available persistent storage, do the caching and retrieval that way.

Comment: That seems like a means to cache _my own_ artifact -- file produced by my build. What I'm looking for is a way to efficiently download somebody else's tarball -- from afar... I know, I can write a script of my own, but I'm puzzled, why -- given their wide variety -- there is no plugin for this among the existing ones. FreeBSD's ports-collection's been doing just this (downloading, verifying, and building 3rd-party sources) for decades, for example...